# How to see core data tables and how to delete the data from a real device

Tags: iphone, core-data

Two questions about Core Data:
1. Is it possible to see the actual data(the db tables) that is stored when using core data?
2. When using the iPhone simulator i can delete the core data db by resetting the simulator. But how can i delete the core data db when using a real device?

Comment: Partial answers to your questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023954/iphone-core-data-simulator
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811207/how-to-view-existing-data-in-core-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac comes with a command line tool sqlite3. You can use it to do queries against the core data database. Not sure if that violates any rules against reverse engineering that might exist in any license agreements.

You can delete the db for convenience during development by deleting your app from the device and reinstalling it. If you don't want to do it by deleting the app, you will have to write some code in your app to delete it I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly view an sqlite store using any sqlite tool including the command line sqlite3 tool. However, (1) Core Data uses a custom undocumented schema so looking at the store doesn't tell you much and (2) the structure of the sqlite store file itself has little relationship to how the managed objects behave in memory. Core Data isn't an sql wrapper.  It just takes the managed objects apart to store them in SQL.  SQL is just an option and Core Data works fine without it.

To "delete the core data db" you simply delete the persistent store file. Look where you initialize the persistentStoreCoordinator (in the Xcode templates, it's in the app delegate.) The URL for the persistent store/s will be there. Just close down the Core Data stack and then delete the store file with NSFileManager. Then restart the Core Data stack.